# Проверка на поддержку необязательного функционала станадартов си

Tags: c, стандарт, c11

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11) про стандарт сказано:

> Новая ревизия стандарта позволяет реализациям не поддерживать определённые части стандарта, включая те, которые раньше надо было поддерживать обязательно (в C99). Программы могут использовать предопределённые макросы для определения того, поддерживает ли реализация часть стандарта или нет.

И перечислены макросы:

| Возможность | Макрос | Доступность в C99 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Анализирование (Annex L) | `__STDC_ANALYZABLE__` | Недоступно |
| Действия с дробными числами по стандарту IEC 60559 (Annex F) | `__STDC_IEC_559__` | Выборочно |
| Арифметика комплексных чисел, совместимая со стандартом IEC 60559 (Annex G) | `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` | Выборочно |
| Интерфейсы проверки границ массива (Annex K) | `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` | Недоступно |
| Типы комплексных чисел (`<complex.h>`) | `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` | Обязательно |
| Многопоточное программирование (`<threads.h>`) | `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` | Недоступно |
| Атомарные операции (`<stdatomic.h>` и квалификатор типа `_Atomic`) | `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__` | Недоступно |
| Массивы переменной длины | `__STDC_NO_VLA__` | Обязательно |

И мне теперь стало неясно, **Если данный функционал доступен, макрос должен определяться? Или если недоступно то он определяется?**

Comment: Для начала необходимо определить версию самого языка C. Для этого есть макрос `__STDC_VERSION__`. А затем открыть стандарт и посмотреть что значит тот или иной макрос. Например, "`__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` The integer constant 1 , intended to indicate that the implementation does not support complex types or the <complex.h> header."

Comment: Скорее не наличие/отсутствие функциональности определяет наличие макроса, а наоборот - если макрос есть, то это гарантирует наличие/отсутствие функциональности. Но если его нет - это еще почти ни о чем не говорит :(